# Importing an element from another URL into an HTML file

Tags: html

Let's say I have a  element in foo.html. How can I import and embed it in another HTML file?

Comment: You want the web client (browser) to look up part of the content on another site, right? Then which client side architecture.framework do you use? Do you for instance use jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [jQuery .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ?

So in another.html you would have:

```
<div id="place-to-embed-element"></div>

<script>
    $( "#place-to-embed-element" ).load( "foo.html #imported-id" );
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this is what I need. Would this work if the other file has no IDs? It has a <body> tag with a <table> tag inside

Comment: Yes it would. You would replace the id selector in my example simply with the tags body and table. So the selector would then read ( "body table" )

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... that sounds odd. What do you mean by "importing"? HTML is a mark-up language, not a "real" programming language like PHP etc., so this functionality is, of course, not given by default. You could start to write PHP or juse JavaScript ... or just explain your question more detailed ;)

(Or just copy your html segment into the other file ]:-> )

Comment: I have basically no HTML knowledge. What I'm actually trying to do is to create a summary page where I pull tables stored in multiple html URLs into a single file.

Comment: In this case I refer to the answer of gloria.iskra, as it would be a rather simple to implent and working solution for you. For more information about include and so, (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) may help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use php...
rename your file from 'file.html' to 'file.php' and copy this into it:

```
<?php
      include("foo.html");
?>
```